# Is it possible to loop through 3 different functions that work on a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a little "slider". A slider that has 3 blocks on the side that are clickable. When you click one of the blocks the "slide" has to change to the corresponding slide. This wasn't a big problem for me.

But the second option I wanted is that there is a looping animation between the slides. But that is something I couldn't complete. And now my question is: is there an easy way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button_1").css("background-color", "#0F0");

$("a#click_1").click(function() {
    $("#item_1").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#item_2").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#item_3").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#button_1").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#0F0"
    }, 1000);
    $("#button_2").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#000"
    }, 1000);
    $("#button_3").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#000"
    }, 1000);
});

$("a#click_2").click(function() {
    $("#item_1").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#item_2").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#item_3").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#button_1").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#000"
    }, 1000);
    $("#button_2").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#00F"
    }, 1000);
    $("#button_3").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#000"
    }, 1000);
});

$("a#click_3").click(function() {
    $("#item_1").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#item_2").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#item_3").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#button_1").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#000"
    }, 1000);
    $("#button_2").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#000"
    }, 1000);
    $("#button_3").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FF0"
    }, 1000);
});
});
```

I already have got this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yauhnhan/VX9Qr/7/

Comment: Yes it is possible. But I'm not in the mood to programm the whole thing for you. You need a global flag, that stores the current active slide and a timeout, that is called in a loop or recursive to switch to the slides time-based. The click actions are separate and should only call a slider-switch function with the currents slide ID passed to it. But why don't you use one of the million ready plugins like [jcarousel](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel)? YOu could then use the callback function of the plugin to implement additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var delay = 1000;

    $("#button_3").css("background-color", "#FF0"); 

  $('.btn').click(function(){

   var item=$($(this).attr('href'));


    $('.item').each(function(i,v){

            $(v).fadeOut(delay);
            $('#button_'+(i+1)).css("background-color", "#000");



    });   

  item.fadeIn(delay);
             $('#button_'+(item.index()+1)).animate({
        backgroundColor: item.css("background-color")
    }, 1000);
    return false;

   });
});​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VX9Qr/14/

Answer (score 0):

You can have it shorter. Give your buttons, items, and anchors common class names (e.g. "click", "item", "btn"):

```
$('a.click').each(function(i){
   $(this).click(function(){
      $('.item').fadeOut(1000).eq(i).stop(true).fadeIn(1000);
      $('.btn').animate({backgroundColor:'#000'},1000)
         .eq(i).stop(true).animate({backgroundColor:'#0F0'},1000);
   }        
}).eq(0).click();
```